# how to remove a task from ScheduledExecutorService with an external button?

Tags: java, android, handler, buttonclick, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a ScheduledExecutorService

```
public void pulsor1(Integer interval) {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            flagPulsor1 = true;
            indexPulsor1++;
        }
    };
    scheduleTaskExecutor1 = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
    scheduleTaskExecutor1.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable,0,interval,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

and I'd like to kill it with the click of a button or with a handler like

```
handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Is there a way to do this?